# Can't download file on dropbox 400 Bad Request

Tags: wget, vagrant, ceph

Guide

https://tracker.ceph.com/projects/ceph/wiki/Ceph_Vagrant_Setup

```
$ wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box
--2020-03-14 12:11:09--  https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box
Resolving www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)... 162.125.80.1
Connecting to www.dropbox.com (www.dropbox.com)|162.125.80.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /s/raw/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box [following]
--2020-03-14 12:11:10--  https://www.dropbox.com/s/raw/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box
Reusing existing connection to www.dropbox.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2020-03-14 12:11:10 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

The file out of date?

Comment: what are you asking? ... have you tried using a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a web browser to visit `https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box` – Dropbox displays a message:

> 404 We can’t find what you’re looking for.

(although displaying the message does require javascript...)

---

Requesting the page via `curl`:

```
$ curl -IL 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box'
HTTP/2 301
...
location: /s/raw/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box
...
HTTP/2 400
```

With a different `User-Agent` header:

```
$ curl -A cruel -IL 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box'
HTTP/2 200
...
$ curl -s -A cruel 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn28qgjn59nud6h/ceph-all-in-one.box' |
> grep -om1 '<title>[^<]*'
<title>Dropbox - Error
```